# Blender Python executable unable to find 3rd party packages

Tags: python

I have installed the 3rd party packages at the required location as shown below--
[image]

And using `pip list` you can see the packages are indeed installed
[image]

It works okay when I try to import then in terminal
[image]

But inside Blender, it can't see the package
[image]

NOTE: the site package is already in the PATH, and restarted Blender many times, still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd but, those packages that I installed were in the `site-packages` of my local python installation not in the blender python. So to solve it I just added the site package path in `sys.path`

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages")
```